# MahApps Metro Theme - Always show dialog windows in front of all other windows in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, microsoft-metro, mahapps.metro

I'm pretty new to WPF and the Metro styling and I ran into the following problem:

I open all my message dialogs from the main window of my application by calling ShowMessageAsync()., even when the actual caller is another window (e.g. a settings window). Now when for example this settings window is open and wants to show a message that the settings have been saved, the dialog appears in between the main and the settings window (which makes sense because the main window is the caller and the settings window is a child of that main window).
What I want is for all dialogs created by ShowMessageAsynch() to be displayed always in front of the screen.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but I could not find a good answer for this anywhere. I ended up minimizing any child windows, opening the message dialog, and then setting the child windows back to normal. I would still be curious to know if there is a better solution for this problem.

```
    private MetroWindow MetroWindow => (MetroWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

    public async Task ShowInfoDialog(string text)
    {
        var childWindows = MetroWindow.OwnedWindows;
        MinimizeChildWindows(childWindows);
        await MetroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Info", text);
        MaximizeChildWindows(childWindows);
    }

    private void MinimizeChildWindows(WindowCollection childWindows)
    {
        foreach (Window win in childWindows)
        {
            win.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }

    private void MaximizeChildWindows(WindowCollection childWindows)
    {
        foreach (Window win in childWindows)
        {
            win.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```